# HTML search option with filters that link to external website

Tags: html

I'm required to use only HTML to create a web form in which the search result will link me to the external website's search results. There are search options with filters that I have included and when I enter the input and select the filters, it links me to the external website but it does not filter out the search from my own web form, meaning that it would treat any search as a normal search without the filters for 'month', '6months' and 'year' option.

https://www.worldscientific.com/search/advanced - The website that I am supposed to link the search result from my web form to.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<style>
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

#border1 {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 500px;
   padding: 15px;
   border: 2px;
}

</style>

<h2>Part 3 - World Science</h2>
<form id="worldscience_search-form" 
  action="https://www.worldscientific.com/action/doSearch?field1=AllField&text1=text1&publication=&Ppub=&AfterMonth=&AfterYear=&BeforeMonth=&BeforeYear=&earlycite=on" method="get" target="_blank" class="jcf-select" autocomplete="off">
<div id="border1">
<div style = "float:left; width:20%">
  <select id="textArea2" name="field1" style = "height:40px; width:120px;">
  <option value="AllField">Anywhere</option>
  <option value="Title">Title</option>
  <option value="Contrib">Author</option>
  <option value="Keyword">Keywords</option>
  <option value="Abstract">Abstract</option>
  </select> 
  <br><br><br>

  <label for="publication">Published in</label> <br><br><br>

  <label>Publication Date</label>
  <input type="hidden" value="AfterYear">
  <input type="hidden" value="BeforeYear">
  <br>
  </div>

  <div style = "float:left; width:20%">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Search term" name="text1" style = "width: 500px; height:40px"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="publication" placeholder="e.g. Journal of Theoretical Biology" style = "width:500px; height :40px">
   <br><br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="Ppub" value="" checked="checked">
      <label>All dates</label>
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Ppub" value="">
      <label>Last</label>
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Ppub" value="">Custom Range
  </div>

  <div style = "float:left; width:50%">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <select id="Ppub" value="" style = "height:40px; width:120px;">
  <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="20181218-20190118">month</option>
    <option value="20180718-20190118">6 months</option>
    <option value="20180118-20190118">year</option></select><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </html>
```

I don't think that I should have coded the values in the option value. How am I supposed to filter out without coding in the dates?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `hidden` inputs: (I only show start of the form)

```
<form id="worldscience_search-form" action="https://www.worldscientific.com/action/doSearch" method="get" target="_blank" class="jcf-select" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="AllField">
  <input type="hidden" name="text1" value="text1">
  <input type="hidden" name="publication" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="Ppub" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="AfterMonth" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="AfterYear" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="BeforeMonth" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="BeforeYear" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="earlycite" value="on">
```